# What is the correct way with Redux to show a method has successfully been called?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I was hoping to call a reducer method in a Redux slice and return true if the logic succeeded and false if it failed but I seem to be getting the following TypeScript error:

> Type '(state: WritableDraft, action: { payload: { strategyId: string; stageId: string; }; type: string; }) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<StrategySlice, { payload: any; type: string; }> | CaseReducerWithPrepare<StrategySlice, PayloadAction<any, string, any, any>>'.
>
> Type '(state: WritableDraft, action: { payload: { strategyId: string; stageId: string; }; type: string; }) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<StrategySlice, { payload: any; type: string; }>'.
>
> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'void | StrategySlice | WritableDraft'.ts(2322)

My code for the method is below:

```
const strategySlice = createSlice({
    name: "strategy",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
deleteStage: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ strategyId: string; stageId: string }>): boolean => {
            const { strategyId, stageId } = action.payload;

            const strategyIndex = findStrategyIndexById(state, strategyId);

            if (strategyIndex !== -1) {
                const strategy = state.strategies[strategyIndex];
                strategy.stages = strategy.stages.filter((stage) => stage.id !== stageId);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
});

export const {
    deleteStage,
} = strategySlice.actions;
export default strategySlice.reducer;
        },
```

I'm seeking advice on the best implementation for this. I'm predominantly trying to prevent the method from silently failing, and to implement error handling with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer needs to return an updated `state` (*or void  since it is using immer, so changes are tracked*).

Your code returns either `true` or `false`.

Your reducer should be similar to

```js
deleteStage: (state, action:PayloadAction<{ strategyId: string; stageId: string }>) => {
  const {
    strategyId,
    stageId
  } = action.payload;

  const strategyIndex = findStrategyIndexById(state, strategyId);

  if (strategyIndex !== -1) {
    const strategy = state.strategies[strategyIndex];
    strategy.stages = strategy.stages.filter((stage) => stage.id !== stageId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there no way to return a boolean to the component calling the dispatch method? E.g. if the delete method fails ideally you'd want a popup to show an error message e.g. "no stage found with x ID?" That was the functionality I was hoping to implement if possible

Comment: @OliviaBates if you want to handle the error, then you set some state property that relates to errors, and then get its value from your component and render whatever you want.